# Keeping requestanimationframe running on tab switch

Tags: javascript, html, browser, requestanimationframe

For the entire loop of my online browser game (including physics) the game is run by the loop

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(renders)
```

but in multiplayer when the player switches tabs this loop stops and they stop interacting with the game server properly (Bullets don't hurt them) is there a way to combat browsers like chrome pausing this loop when a user switches tabs?

the entire front end of my code is available on http://www.gowar.io

This is not a duplicate because I need to keep a persistent connection to my server somehow and keep physics updated, not just update the graphics after the user comes back

Comment: Unfortunately no. When users switch tabs, chrome and other browsers give much lower priority to rendering to prevent pages from hogging too much CPU/memory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make requestAnimationFrame() Animation Persist When on Different Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35028470/make-requestanimationframe-animation-persist-when-on-different-tab)

Comment: @FrankerZ this is not a duplication because I need to keep physics and my connection persistent not just update the graphics when my user returns to the tab

Comment: @FrankerZ is there a way to detect when this happens and run just a physics/server loop instead?

Comment: blur event on window

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm sorry I don't know what that means

Comment: So, you've written a game, with multiplayer interactions and graphics etc, and you have no idea what a `blur` event on `window` is?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event - you'll also want `focus` event to know when the window (tab) has focus again

Comment: Yeah, sorry I'm a noob I've only been coding for 2.5 weeks learning as fast as I can though ...

Comment: blur event will trigger when user switches tabs (or away from browser) - focus event will trigger when user comes back ... so ... when blur, run your physics  loop without using any animation frames, and when user comes back, restart the animation frame stuff

Comment: So, who wrote the game?

Comment: @JaromandaX well, I have 100% except a prototype function I stole

Comment: @JaromandaX so use a function that detects the blur and run an animation loop or just a physics loop with something like FPS? or is there an easier way to escape the loop and switch

Comment: OK - impressive that you've gotten so much done without knowing the basics of javascript in a browser ... I hope the link I provided has enough information for you to figure out how to detect when the tab loses/gains focus :p

Comment: `an easier way to escape the loop and switch` - you've posted NO CODE - so, the answer is a pineapple

Comment: @JaromandaX oh, I thought the link with my source code was sufficient, my apologies, thanks for the help though

Comment: nobody is going to trawl through hundreds of lines of code when the issue is with a specific block (it seems)